# Designing a chatbot personal project with zero coding experience, using an existing platform

Tags: natural-language-processing, chat-bots, natural-language-understanding

My girlfriend has a masters degree in linguistics and would like to create an AI chatbot personal project to show potential employers her linguistics skills since she is struggling to find a job.

Unfortunately she doesn't know how to program except for extremely basic Python skills. She has been searching for weeks for tools to create a chatbot without needing to program, refusing to ask on forums for help so I'm asking the StackExchange community. Sort of like a plugin/widget for Slack, Facebook Messenger or website that you can just install on your website and just concentrate on the workflow/data/conversational design in a similar way to programming in Scratch or Node-Red.

I know nothing about NLP, neural networks or anything like that and I can't understand for the life of me  what exactly it is a linguist needs to do in AI. Adversely, she doesn't have the computer knowledge to understand how an API works, or how to get some sort of service and a chat interface are needed to bootstrap her conversational designs with some code somewhere.

So my question is: Is there a way for a linguist to create a chatbot without knowing programming or going in too deep, all by themselves? We looked at tools like hubspot.com, where the chatbot design is either multiple choices questions with predefined answers or offers expensive paid solutions for companies. I'm sure there are free educational or community open-source platforms doing this.

Comment: Dialogflow is a good way to create and deploy an alexa skill/api using nlp, but that is again an api, but also has a GUI, you can just go through a medium/youtube tutorial to get a basic app, get some help (maybe hire a professional on fiverr/upwork for coding stuff) to create an app that showcases her linguistic skills

Comment: Thanks friend! For the past 5 hours, I've been searching for tutorials and online courses on DialogFlow to find which are best suited for her and some of them look promising. Also found lots of easy class for Python beginners. Unless someone else has a better solution, Dialogflow and Ptyhon could be the way to go.